# Django-cms and Editorial workflows

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-cms

I need to implement workflows in my Django-CMS application at work. But form the Django-CMS feature list, we can read:

**Editorial workflow**

Workflows for publishing and approval.

I tried to search for it and didn't find anything. I've search the Django-CMS documentation (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html) and couldn't find something there either.

Does anyone has a clue about Workflows in Django-CMS (especially for the pages system) ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? If you set http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-moderator to True, you get the moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn on CMS_MODERATION in Django-CMS, you will get three icons next to each page in the page list view. From left to right, these control

- whether changes to this page will require moderator approval
- whether changes to this page's children will require moderator approval
- whether changes to this page's descendents will require moderator approval

When you create or change a page, you will be able to save it, and preview the page or new version of the page on your site, but it will require moderator approval before the page or new version of the page is visible to end users.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I founded yesterday in the afternoon, but wasn't able to add an answer to my own question due to the reputation system.

Comment: Related documentation about this setting:
[link](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html?highlight=CMS_MODERATOR#cms-moderator)

Comment: Although this is a good answer at the time of writing, be aware that the CMS_MODRATOR option in Django-CMS is depricated and should not be implemented, read more; https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2012/10/03/the-future-moderator/

Comment: The above blog link is dangling. This one is valid: https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2012/10/03/the-future-of-moderator/ ("The future of moderator") TL;DR _We'll kill moderator. We'll replace it with something better. If you don't like that, tell us what you need to re-build it outside CMS core._

Answer (score 3):

*An update for 2016:*

### No Editorial Workflow in django CMS 3 (yet)

django CMS 3 (v3.3.2 as of today) has **no editorial workflow**. This feature was removed in version 2.3, and replaced by the concept of "simple publishing" (2 versions of content: draft, public). Read the [related blog post](https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2012/10/03/the-future-of-moderator/) from Divio for their motivation.

For version 3.5 there is some extended moderation support planned via an addon, as [explained by Angelo Dini in a current comment](https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2012/10/03/the-future-of-moderator/#comment-2856242320) on the original blog post from 2012. Don't bet on it, though.

### Control over Editing

If what you want is, at least, some control over editing, e.g. "some users are allowed to create and edit only but can't publish changes", then you're in luck. It works as follows:

Control over editing goes with the following formula, it's a **combination of 3 things**:

> "Staff" status + App permissions + CMS permissions

The first two are plain Django concepts (from `django.contrib.auth`, see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/)) and the latter comes [from django CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/topics/permissions.html). All 3 play together, here's why:

- Without **"Staff" status** no editing is allowed at all, no CMS toolbar for front-end editing is shown either. Note that this status cannot be set on a group, it must be set on individual users. (d'oh!)
- Without all **app permissions** (cms, djangocms-, cmsplugin-, zinnia) assigned to the group (or user directly) there is no editing; the CMS toolbar will be shown and you can typically double-click on content to initiate editing, but django CMS will tell you that you have no permission.
- Omitting some of the **CMS permissions** (e.g. create, publish) disables the buttons on the CMS toolbar. That's about it. There is no message instructing the user what to do or explanation about what is happening (acknowledged, it's difficult to provide a generic solution here), neither are emails or other notifications sent (of course, there is no such thing as an editorial workflow).

IOW, it's possible to split your users into groups and allow them to do just some specific things (editing only, publishing only, etc.), but the user notifications, a central concept to workflow implementions, are not available in django CMS v3.3.

**EDIT:** See "[Editorial workflow for django CMS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms-developers/tUD8x8nc8HE)" in the django CMS developers G+ group for details and a demo of a related implementation.